# How to idiomatically structure a React app to edit both single and multiple instances of a model

Tags: reactjs

I’m trying to figure out how to structure some React code in the context of Rails.

Here’s (something analogous to) my situation. My web app has a Graph model: it lets you build customized graphs for a variety of metrics. I made a React component called GraphEditor which lets you edit graphs, and a component called GraphViewer which displays a graph. GraphEditor maintains top-level state of its graph, and has the logic to serialize its graph and send it to the backend. As well as storing the top-level state of its graph, GraphEditor also stores the results of a bunch of mildly expensive

Sometimes I want to be able to deal with groups of graphs. Eg I have all the graphs by one particular user; they should be able to create, destroy, view, and edit those graphs. How should I do this?

My first thought was to build a MultiGraphApp component which takes a list of graphs and maintains state to tell it which graph the user is currently looking at. It will then render a GraphEditor or GraphViewer of that graph. This makes me uncomfortable, because these child components of my app have lots of internal state.

I could also make my MultiGraphApp store the state of all the graphs, and then rewrite my GraphEditor component to have some callbacks passed in for when it wants to save its graph. This makes sense, but now it means that I can’t make a GraphEditor that isn’t wrapped in a MultiGraphApp, which is kind of annoying because I want to use the GraphEditor on its own sometimes.

One other solution would be to shrug and give up on making this a single-page app, and just have Rails handle creating and switching between graphs; in this model, switching between graphs is just like following a link.

Which of these is most React-idiomatic?

Answer (score 0):

Your design is mostly correct.  The piece of the puzzle you are missing is Flux.

Flux is a design pattern that abstracts away items that should be considered part of the "global state".  Your usecase is a perfect example;  you need a place to store *all* of your graphs, and then disseminate that information throughout the application where applicable.

Flux helps you do that by providing a "source of truth".  It's the source of your data river.

A Flux implementation of your system might have a `GraphStore` which holds an array of all `graphs`.  It could also store a value for `selectedGraphIndex`, along with a selector function;

```
GraphStore.getSelectedGraph = function(){
    return this.graphs[this.selectedGraphIndex];
}
```

You might also want to look at REDUX, which is a very popular implementation of the Flux design pattern.